# Using tee in a bash script (on Solaris)

Tags: bash, solaris, tee

I'm trying to build a simple log file along with a running script that I've hacked together. The lines in question look like the following:

```
TEE="/usr/bin/tee"
TO_LOG="/usr/bin/tee >> $LOG_DIR/hosts.`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`.log"
```

Then those two get used like this:

```
echo "something happened!" | $TO_LOG
```

Unfortunately the only thing this is doing is creating an empty filed literally named `>>` in my CWD. Running this script with `bash -x` shows the redirect with append operator getting single quoted - although I'm not sure if that's literally happening or if that's just being appended by bash in interactive debug mode.

```
+ echo 'something happened!'
+ /usr/bin/tee '>>' /backups/logs/mylog.20110801-182337.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tee` itself is intended to do the file writing. I think you want:

```
/usr/bin/tee -a $LOG_DIR/hosts.`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`.log
```

The `-a` option causes `tee` to append, rather than truncate, the file (similar to how `>>` appends whereas `>` truncates in most shells).

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you want...

```
TEE="/usr/bin/tee"
LOG="$LOG_DIR/hosts.$(date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S').log"
to_log() {
    $TEE -a $LOG
}

echo "test" | to_log
```